# How to approximate a trigonometric curve by Bezier curves?

Tags: interpolation, bezier-curve

Let me ask how to approximate a trigonometric curve by Bezier curves? Is there any known algorithm?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try [this](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/Maplesque/Bezier/BestFittingBezierCurves.ppt) Page 13. Codes are [here](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/Maplesque/Bezier/).

Comment: @Nunoxic Thank you very much.